# Brainfuck NASM compiler in Clojure

Tags: clojure, compiler

I've made a simple brainfuck compiler, I feel like my code is unreadable and messy, how can I improve it?

src/core.clj

```
(ns brainfuck-asm.core
  (:require [brainfuck-asm.parse :as parse]
            [brainfuck-asm.optimize :as optimize]
            [brainfuck-asm.generate :as generate]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.string :as str])
  (:gen-class))

(defn- ^:const remove-initial-comment-loop
  ([sequence] (case (first sequence)
                \[ (remove-initial-comment-loop (drop 1 sequence) 1)
                sequence))
  ([[character & chars] matching-bracket-count]
   (cond
     (nil? character) (throw (IllegalArgumentException. "Unbalanced braces"))
     (zero? matching-bracket-count)  (str character (str/join chars))
     (not= 0 matching-bracket-count) (recur chars (case character
                                                    \[ (inc matching-bracket-count)
                                                    \] (dec matching-bracket-count)
                                                    matching-bracket-count)))))

(defn- ^:const optimize-ast [ast]
  (map #(update % :statements optimize/optimize-sentence) ast))

(defn- ^:const remove-illegal-characters [input]
  (let [legal-characters #{\+ \- \< \> \. \, \[ \]}]
    (filter #(contains? legal-characters %) input)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [input-file-name (first args)]
    (cond
      (nil? input-file-name) (println "Please specify a brainfuck source file to compile")
      (.exists (io/file input-file-name))
      (let [brainfuck-code (slurp input-file-name)]
        (if (parse/balanced? brainfuck-code)
          (-> brainfuck-code
              remove-illegal-characters
              remove-initial-comment-loop
              parse/generate-ast
              optimize-ast
              generate/generate-assembly
              println)
          (println "Your code's braces are unbalanced (missing [ or ]).")))
      :else (println (str "Cannot find: " input-file-name "\nExiting...")))))
```

src/generate.clj

```
(ns brainfuck-asm.generate
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn- ^:const prepare-statements [statements]
  (->> statements flatten (map #(str "    " %)) (str/join \newline)))

(defn- ^:const generate-segment [name & statements]
  (str "segment ." name \newline (prepare-statements statements) \newline))

(defn- ^:const generate-label [name & statements]
  (str \newline name \: \newline (prepare-statements statements) \newline))

(defn- ^:const generate-loop-condition [statement]
  ["cmp byte [eax], 0" (str "jne " (:argument statement)) "ret"])

(def ^:private ^:const print-cell
  (generate-label "print_cell" "push eax" "mov ecx, eax" "mov eax, 0x04"
                  "mov ebx, 0x01" "mov edx, 0x01" "int 0x80" "pop eax" "ret"))

(def ^:private ^:const read-definition
  (generate-label "read" "mov ecx, eax" "push eax" "mov eax, 0x03" "mov ebx, 0x00"
                  "mov edx, 0x01" "int 0x80" "pop eax" "ret"))

(def ^:private ^:const exit ["mov eax, 1" "xor ebx, ebx" "int 0x80"])

(defn- ^:const statement->asm
  "Translates an statement to assembly code"
  [statement]
  (case (:type statement)
    :inc         "inc byte [eax]"
    :dec         "dec byte [eax]"
    :inc-pointer "inc eax"
    :dec-pointer "dec eax"
    :add         (str "add byte [eax], " (:argument statement))
    :sub         (str "sub byte [eax], " (:argument statement))
    :add-pointer (str "add eax, " (:argument statement))
    :sub-pointer (str "sub eax, " (:argument statement))
    :call-print  "call print_cell"
    :call-read   "call read"
    :call-loop   (str "call loop" (:argument statement))
    :call-exit   exit
    :loop-end    (generate-loop-condition statement)
    :load-array  "mov eax, array"
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str (:type statement) " is not a proper statement type")))))

(defn ^:const generate-assembly [ast]
  (str
   (generate-segment "bss" "array: resb 30000")
   \newline
   (generate-segment "text" "global _start")
   (str/join (map #(apply generate-label (:name % "_start") (map statement->asm (:statements %))) ast))
   print-cell
   read-definition))
```

src/optimize.clj

```
(ns brainfuck-asm.optimize
  (:require [brainfuck-asm.parse :as parse]
            [clojure.zip :as zip]))

(defn- ^:const optimize-two-statements
  "Defines the rules for optimzing statements.
  Returns nil if statements cannot be optimized, else the combination of statements"
  [statement statement1]
  (cond
    (= (statement :type) (statement1 :type) :inc)                                (parse/create-statement :add 2)
    (= (statement :type) (statement1 :type) :dec)                                (parse/create-statement :sub 2)
    (= (statement :type) (statement1 :type) :inc-pointer)                        (parse/create-statement :add-pointer 2)
    (= (statement :type) (statement1 :type) :dec-pointer)                        (parse/create-statement :sub-pointer 2)
    (and (= (statement :type) :add) (= (statement1 :type) :inc))                 (update statement :argument inc)
    (and (= (statement :type) :sub) (= (statement1 :type) :dec))                 (update statement :argument inc)
    (and (= (statement :type) :add-pointer) (= (statement1 :type) :inc-pointer)) (update statement :argument inc)
    (and (= (statement :type) :sub-pointer) (= (statement1 :type) :dec-pointer)) (update statement :argument inc)
    :else                                                                        nil))

(defn- ^:const optimize-sentence-zipper
  "Takes a zipped sentence and optimizes it"
  ([sentence-zipper]
   (if (-> sentence-zipper zip/next zip/end?)
     (zip/root sentence-zipper)
     (let [replacement (optimize-two-statements (zip/node sentence-zipper) (-> sentence-zipper zip/next zip/node))]
       (case replacement
         nil (recur (zip/next sentence-zipper))
         (recur (-> sentence-zipper
                    (zip/replace replacement)
                    zip/next
                    zip/remove)))))))

(defn ^:const optimize-sentence
  "Turns a vector of statements (sentence) into an optimized sentence.
  Returns a vector"
  [sentence]
  (optimize-sentence-zipper (-> sentence zip/vector-zip zip/next)))
```

src/parse.clj

```
(ns brainfuck-asm.parse)

(defn ^:const balanced?
  "Returns whether brackets contained in expr are balanced"
  ([expr] (balanced? expr 0))
  ([[x & xs] count]
   (cond (neg? count) false
         (nil? x) (zero? count)
         (= x \[) (recur xs (inc count))
         (= x \]) (recur xs (dec count))
         :else (recur xs count))))

(defn ^:const create-statement
  ([type]
   {:type type})
  ([type argument]
   {:type      type
    :argument argument}))

(defn- ^:const craete-loop [name]
  {:name name
   :type :loop
   :statements []})

(defn- ^:const brainfuck->ast-node [character]
  (case character
    \+ (create-statement :inc)
    \- (create-statement :dec)
    \> (create-statement :inc-pointer)
    \< (create-statement :dec-pointer)
    \. (create-statement :call-print)
    \, (create-statement :call-read)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (format "%s is not a valid brainfuck symbol" character)))))

(defn ^:const generate-ast
  ([brainfuck-symbols]
   {:pre [(balanced? brainfuck-symbols)]}
   (generate-ast '() {:type :entrypoint :statements [{:type :load-array}]} '() brainfuck-symbols 0))
  ([ast current-label stack [character & characters] loop-count]
   (case character
     nil (apply conj ast (update current-label :statements conj (create-statement :call-exit)) stack)
     \[  (recur ast
                (craete-loop (str "loop" loop-count))
                (conj stack (update current-label :statements conj (create-statement :call-loop loop-count)))
                characters
                (inc loop-count))
     \]  (recur (conj ast (update current-label :statements conj (create-statement :loop-end (:name current-label))))
                (peek stack)
                (pop stack)
                characters
                loop-count)
     (recur ast
            (update current-label :statements conj (brainfuck->ast-node character))
            stack
            characters
            loop-count))))
```